# How To Pass JSON to a WebGet

Tags: json, rest, webget

I have the following WebGet:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetAssignments/{data}")]
    [Description("GetAssignments")]
    BASE.BaseResponse<object> GetAssignments(String data);
```

Called thusly:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify(advancedSearchDataXml);

    Helper.Service.Call({
        api: 'HomeApi',
        url: '?method=GetAssignments/' + data,
        method: 'GET',
        //data: advancedSearchDataXml,
        controlId: '',
        showProgress: true,
        onSuccess: function (result) {
    ...
```

where data is

```
{"searchquery":
    "<SearchQuery>
        <genericsearch></genericsearch>
        <region>MA</region><market>RL</market>
        <recordcount>5000</recordcount>
    </SearchQuery>"
}
```

This fails with a "EXCEPTION: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `?method=` instead have only `'GetAssignments/'+ data`  .. also add a break point in your controller to make sure the right method is being hit.

Comment: ?method= is required by the  Helper.Service.Call function, and is correct for my app. And my controller is being hit.

Comment: Can you show the controller code? I want to see what is on the base... method that is being called.